# Passing objects to workers

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying my luck with a Mozilla extension.

I want to use the below code to read line by line from a file and store the content in an array. And I've been trying to use workers to do this task in the background, away from the main thread. The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to pass neither "Components" nor the input stream to the worker in the `postMessage()` function without receiving a `DataCloneError` error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Line_by_line

Any ideas on how and what to pass to the worker to make it work ? Or if not, then how to do this task asynchronously, if not by using workers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass anything except pure `JSON` to worker and both `Components` and any of `Components.classes` are not serializable to `JSON`.

Take a look at JavaScript module [`NetUtil.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/NetUtil.jsm), it seems to be ok to use network utilities for local file reading. Eventually, everything is still socket.

Also, you may just make code from your snippet asynchronous with good old `setInterval`.